# Android Studio HAXM reports "Haxm can only be installed on windows or mac"

Tags: android-studio, haxm

The set up is a x470 Master SLI/ac

I am attempting to set up and install Android Studio. I have enabled in bios the SVM mode and IOMMU. I'm currently on a Windows PC. The error I get is as follows:

```
Unable to install haxm.
Haxm can only be installed on windows or mac.
please file agains android studio

After clicking finish...
Installation did not complete successfully. See the IDE log for details.
```

Comment: Also x470 here, same problem. Hyper-V is disabled. I do however have WSL enabled. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

i am not 100% sure about my solution but try a lower version of haxm ?